# Why am I getting a list of tags instead of numbers?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import requests
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import re

towns = pd.DataFrame()

url = f"https://www.city-data.com/city/Adak-Alaska.html"
page = requests.get(url).text
doc = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

sex_population = str(doc.find(id="population-by-sex"))
(males, females) = [float(x) for x in re.findall(r"(?<=\()[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?=\%\))", sex_population)]
print(males, females)

religion_population = str(doc.find(id="religion"))
atheist = float(re.findall("(?<=None<\/td><td>)[0-9,]*(?=<\/td><td>)", 
religion_population)[0].replace(",", ""))
print(atheist)

total_population = str(doc.find(id="city-population"))
residents = float(re.findall("(?<=</b> )[0-9]*", total_population)[0].replace(",", ""))
print(residents)

believers = re.findall("(<?<td>)[0-9,]*", religion_population)
for x in believers:
    x.replace(",", "")
print(believers)
```

instead of printing out a list of numbers like I'm expecting, print(believers) prints out a list of < td >.
What am I doing wrong here? I checked my work on regex 101.

Comment: you may need to get `.text` or `.get_text()`

Comment: why not use BeautifulSoup function `.find_all()` instead of convertin all to string and using `regex.

Comment: As for the actual regex, `<?<td>` is in a capturing group instead of `[0-9,]*`, so `findall` won't even contain the numbers, but instead contain a bunch of `<td>`'s or `<<td>`'s (see this [example](https://tio.run/##fY7LCsIwEEX3@Yohq0Tqs62oVF34ES5EpLSxFmoSxgHx62PSVqgu3M1lDude@6Kb0fHKonP13RokQMXYg7DWFWyBZ1Tu5os4yab@gJCSdNkGzp5odHWxOZFCHWCR7QMhT7PxOjqPOCsMoipoyHSI6BHJGbO@iwQ/Bhv05AZ4BH6FQDW51rrMm0Z81bVfv1FK@REcurJ/ip89A4lzbw) code). The correct regex should be `<?<td>([0-9,]*)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use BeautifulSoup's functions instead of regex - `.find_all()`, `.get_text()`,

**EDIT:** I added `DataFrame` to calculate `percentage`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.city-data.com/city/Adak-Alaska.html"
response = requests.get(url)
#print('status:', response.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

religion_population = soup.find(id="religion").find_all('tr')

data = []

for row in religion_population:
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    if columns:
        religion = columns[0].get_text(strip=True)
        number   = columns[1].get_text(strip=True).replace(",", "")
        print(f'religion: {religion} | number: {number}')
        data.append([religion, int(number)])
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['religion', 'number'])
df['percentage'] = (df['number'] / df['number'].sum()) * 100

print(df)
```

Result:

```
religion: Orthodox | number: 754
religion: Evangelical Protestant | number: 232
religion: Catholic | number: 185
religion: Other | number: 112
religion: Mainline Protestant | number: 82
religion: None | number: 4196

                 religion  number  percentage
0                Orthodox     754   13.558712
1  Evangelical Protestant     232    4.171912
2                Catholic     185    3.326740
3                   Other     112    2.014026
4     Mainline Protestant      82    1.474555
5                    None    4196   75.454055
```

---

**By The Way:**

BeautifulSoup's functions `.find()`, `.find_all()` can also use [regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) but to search tags. But it can also can use [functions](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to select elements.

Comment: I'm trying to just get the numbers so I can calculate the percentage of the population that says none for their religion.

Comment: you have to convert to `int()` to make calculations. And if you put data in DataFrame then it will be simpler to make any calculations.

Comment: for percentages shouldn't I be using floats?

Comment: if you divide `int` values then you get `float` result - so data can be `int`. I added code which calculates percentage.

Comment: So how do I grab those specific percentages? The eventual goal is to put all the values I'm using into columns then get it to grab every city on the website and make them each an individual row, so that I can do some machine learning on them.

Comment: I create DataFrame with values in indivudal rows - so you can copy rows to other DataFrame.